# Concise way of querying many identical files

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

Is there a concise way of writing one query to run the equivalent of the following queries on 40 identical files:

```
SELECT * FROM file1                       
where created > '2017-03-01-00.00.00.000000'
and regDate < 20170101

SELECT * FROM file2                       
where created > '2017-03-01-00.00.00.000000'
and regDate < 20170101

.
.
.

SELECT * FROM file40                       
where created > '2017-03-01-00.00.00.000000'
and regDate < 20170101
```

Comment: What's the expected result if one file is missing? Do you want no data at all, or data from the 39 existing files?

Comment: All files will be present, just need to know if there is any data meeting the criteria is on any of the files.

Comment: A huge UNION ALL? If it's a one-time query, hard-coded. If frequently run, and the number of files will differ, some kind of dynamic query.

Comment: Is it the same 40 files all the time, but the specific criteria may change?  Are you simply trying to find out whether any such record exists, or do you need to process data in those rows?

Comment: Yes, same 40 files but criteria may change. Just finding out if data exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer seems to be:

```
with combinedFile as (  

SELECT * FROM file1

union all                                         
SELECT * FROM file02                          

.
.
.

union all                                         
SELECT * FROM file40 )                        


SELECT * FROM combinedFile                               
where created > '2017-03-01-00.00.00.000000'    
and regDate < 20170101
```

Thanks to everyone who helped me reach this answer by posting comments!